# how to make static variable that can be used in any method of a class in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, static-variables

I have declare the static varaible in a homeController class that extends controller. The value of static variable has been changed by a method but when i try to access the variable it gives me null that is the value before changed. Is n't it suppose to give the changed value?

my code is like this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller{
private static $r_id = null;
public function amethod(){
self::$r_id = 14; //here i have changed the value
}
public function bmethod(){
return self::$r_id; //this result me null while i expect 14
}
}
```

where did i went wrong or how can i use a variable of one method in another.

Comment: Are you actually running those methods somewhere..?  What you have will work, you just need to actually run `self::amethod()`

Comment: @BizzyBob this is just illustration code..as per my real code the amethod will take the request from a form and save it to database. the b method need r_id to find the row in a database.

Comment: Are these happening in separate requests..?  The static variable is only available for the duration of the request.  For separate requests, you may want to store info in the session.